# Overheating problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, overheating, hybrid-graphics

I'm still having an overheating problem in Ubuntu 14.04. I have heard that the problem would vanish in the new version (Ubuntu 14.04), but my HP Pavilion g6 laptop is still overheating. It's not normal because it's not overheating in the same way when I'm using Windows 7. I have done a search, and it seems that the problem is because my laptop has a hybrid graphics card.

Is it true that it's because of my hybrid graphics card? If it is how can I fix it? If not, what is the cause of the problem and how can I fix it?

The result of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

Comment: If your CPU is Intel then read this http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

Comment: Ubuntu is not using `Intel pstate`

Comment: @kenn intel_pstate is available on Ubuntu 14.04 with the kernek parameter `intel_pstate=enable`

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses kernel 3.13 and since 3.13 there is a major bug in controlling the fans!

I saw reports about affected HP and DELL laptops, and even Macbook Air. The symptom on my HP Compaq nx8220 is that the fan speed is set according to the temperature, but only once at boot time or when resumed after suspend! At boot time the temp is usually medium and the fan stays at medium speed. But after resume the temp is low, the fan stays off and the system overheats easily.

I was able to fix it today (July 13 2014) with a pre-release of kernel 3.13.0-32 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Careful users should wait a few days to get this fixed kernel as a normal update!

From what I have read the problem was a kernel patch called "ACPI / AC: convert ACPI ac driver to platform bus" which has now been reverted in kernel 3.13.0-31 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update with the results of:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

This will tell you which card is in use. In most dual graphics set ups, like optimus, there is a primary graphics device, and a discrete device. Windows 8.1 handles switching between graphics mode very easily, Ubuntu struggles sometimes depending on the card.

It looks like this may help you out as well:
[AMD - Ubuntu Driver Install Help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

In any case, you need to get drivers that will allow you to use the "primary" GPU all the time, and only use the discrete GPU when needed, for example when gaming or doing anything graphics intensive.

Comment: The result of lspci | grep VGAis                                 :00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

Comment: What kind of temperatures are you getting? Is the pc shutting down? Can you switch between the two cards? Looks like your using the right card, and your discrete card is secondary. There are tools you can download as well to reduce temperatures, I use TLP and laptop-mode-tools which you can get from the repos. They let me run my notebook at about 30-40 celcius.

Comment: the graphical mode of laptop-mode-tools is not working  i didn't find TLP

Comment: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html for TLP