# Ubuntu not working need new os?

Tags: windows, xubuntu

Hello everyone i need your help.  I have installed  ubuntu but it is experiencing  a lot of  overheat issues and it  can't  stay on for more than 5 mins.  So i decided  to  install windows but it is showing an error that it cannot be installed  on  disk 0 parition 1.

So i was asking is there any good os which does not  have  any overheat issues and is easily installable

Answer (score 0):

Try the options given here : [Overheating problem in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477731/overheating-problem-in-ubuntu-14-04)

If you still experience heating issues and still want to switch to a new os :

Ubuntu uses four main file systems Ext2/Ext3/Ext4 and Btrfs as Ubuntu natives, while on Windows it is FAT32 and NTFS. You cannot install windows on a Ext2/Ext3/Ext4 partition.

Use KDE Partition manager, or any other partition manager to create a new NTFS partition for your windows os.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/partitionmanager/

If you wish to remove ubuntu completely :

Boot into windows installation media and click Shift + f10 to open up command prompt.

Execute these commands :

- diskpart
- list disk          (to see the disks on you system )
- select disk 0      ( if ubuntu is installed on disk0 )
- clean

NOTE : **Using clean will erase your data**. if you want to completely format you hard disk, you can use the command > clean all

The deleted disk will now appear as unallocated space in disk partition manager. Now you can install windows by creating a new NTFS partition during windows installation setup.